# SQL Azure: The transaction has been initialized but has not generated any log records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

I have a transaction in a SQL azure database with a database_transaction_state of 3 which according to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186957.aspx) means the transaction has "been initialized but has not generated any log records".

This transaction can be seen by running the following command within SQL Azure:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_database_transactions
```

I'm unable to roll this transaction back using the ROLLBACK TRAN command, I keep geeting a "The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION" error.

If I leave this transaction in this state could this potentially cause log growth issues down the line and will it need rectifying? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be worried about the transaction log space in Azure and this will be maintained by the platform based on the your performance tier. However you can still look into sys.database_files to see the log growth. Try dbcc opentran (SQL V12) to see if any active transactions and kill the session if needed.